# Blocking Transaction Issue with SSIS

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssis

I have a SSIS package that starts a transaction, then marks existing records in the destination table as inactive.  I then have a data flow task that inserts the new records before commiting or rolling back the transaction.

The problem I am having is the DF task is hanging due to a deadlock.  The package has been running fine for a month, but for some reason it just started having lock issues.

[image]

I have tried setting different transaction levels, but no luck so far.  From what I can tell here is the lock condition:

[image]

Comment: Is it blocked or deadlocked? deadlocked one of the transactions will get automatically rolled back with an error stating deadlock was detected.

Comment: Martin - You are correct.  It appears to be a block.

Comment: So you need to track down the process holding the `X` lock that is blocking you. Or is that from the same package too?

Comment: Same package.  When I get the query for the X lock, it is saying it is the select statement from the source table (I have a nolock hint).  However, if I disable the update statement before the DF task, the issue goes away.

Comment: So looks like the connection used in the dataflow is a different one from the connection in the execute sql task. So it isn't part of the same transaction. And actually is deadlocked but in SSIS not SQL Server.

Comment: Hi Martin.  I verified that they use the same connection and that retain same connection = True.  What's perplexing is that is has been running flawlessly for a month, but suddenly is blocking.  It's like there is a hidden lock that I can't find.

Comment: Does the bulk insert use fast load?

Comment: Yes, fast load with lock table unchecked.

Comment: See the top comment here https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedbackdetail/view/405565/ssis-database-connection-not-reused-across-destinations-after-a-multicast

Comment: Excellent find.  Changing from fast load did the trick!  Thank you!

Comment: It's not a good idea to create transactions in T-SQL on SSIS packages. Use the built-in transaction handling.

Answer (score 0):

Can you show me the execution plan?  Are there any clustered index scans? if there are you can solve this pretty quickly.

To fix the problem, we need to create a non-clustered index on the column identified in the Predicate section.  The effect of doing this will be a non-clustered index seek (which is more of a direct path to the data than a scan) and it will bypass the deadlock problem.